# Laptop hangs on POST and does not finish except on rare occasions

Tags: laptop, post, laptop-repair

I have an old Toshiba Satellite A100 laptop that hangs on POST when I try to start it. On rare occasions it does finish the POST and boots Windows successfully, but most times it just finishes it partially and continues to hang. I can enter the BIOS though when it has frozen, but I have to open the DVD-drive first for some reason. The keyboard is not quite right either, and I can't navigate the BIOS properly because the arrow keys doesn't work. I tried an external keyboard, but the problem persisted. I have tried to remove the memory, hard drive, and battery to see if any of these were the problem, but it did not solve it. The one logical thing left to do would be to remove the CMOS battery, but the "brilliant" engineers at Toshiba have place it such that a complete disassembly of the machine is necessary. What this all boils down to is basically the question of whether I can "save" this machine and get it to boot properly, or if I should just send it off to recycling. I suspect it might need costly repairs, but I can't bring myself to throw it away before I have made sure it's completely dead.

Answer (score 0):

If opening your DVD drive helps the drive might be the problem. So remove it and see if it boots without delay. The same goes for the keyboard. Remove it and only use a external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Does the laptop beep strangely when you turn it on? The beeps may indicate a problem, see [Computer POST and beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). You may have to flash the bios.

Comment: No, there's no beeps. I don't think I can flash the BIOS since I can't pass the POST.